# Does this sentence structure work/flow?

Tags: sentence

"Under 2 weeks to go until our official 2018-19 full brochure is released.
Receive your free brochure, delivered straight to your door, on the link below."

It is particularly that second line. I'm not sure if the sentence doesn't flow.

Answer (score 1):

"On" is the wrong word. The brochure will not be delivered literally on top of the link on someone's computer screen. The brochure will be delivered *by clicking on* the link. I would edit the sentence to say "Receive your free brochure, delivered straight to your door, by clicking on the link below."